# Multiparameter eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am mostly asking about terminology here.

**Background** A generalized linear eigenvalue problem is of the form $Ax=\lambda B x$, where $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue and $x$ is the eigenvector. We can write this in the form that makes it evident that it is linear in $\lambda$: $(A-\lambda B) x = 0$. A polynomial eigenvalue problem is of the form
$$ \left[\sum_{k=0}^N \lambda^k A_k\right] x = 0$$

**Question** Now, I am wondering what you would call an eigenvalue problem which is "bilinear" in its eigenparameters:
$$ \left[ A\lambda\mu + B\lambda + C\mu + D \right] x = 0 $$
where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the eigenvalues, $x$ is the eigenvector and $A,B,C,D$ are square matrices.

Has this kind of problem been studied? I know this is generally a nonlinear eigenvalue problem of the form $M(\lambda,\mu)x = 0$, but it seems like there is important additional structure here.

Comment: [Here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2009.12.022), a more general quadratic multiparameter eigenproblem is considered. [Here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2009.02.008) is a related paper.

Comment: @J. M.: Wow, I didn't realize you can linearize the problem like that. Thanks for the reference.